# How to display uploaded image using path in angularJS and MVC?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have uploaded an image using AngularJs on a particular path. Now I want to display uploaded *Single* image  in a div from that path.

Please help me to know how to display uploaded image?

In my AngularJs Controller:

```
$scope.uploadUrl = function () {
    var url = "~/uploads";
}
```

And in view;

```
    <div ng-controller="FileUploadController">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" file-upload/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    <div>

    <div>
        <img src="http://{{uploadUrl}}"/>
        <img ng-src="http://{{uploadUrl}}"/>
    </div>
```

I want to display image on click of upload button so that it could display image after uploading.

Comment: return imagePath from server the assign that imgpath to `src` of image.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help-

html-

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img src="http://{{url}}"/>
    <img ng-src="http://{{url}}"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and controller-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl',
   function ($scope) {
    $scope.url = 'cdn1.www.st-hatena.com/users/ho/howdy39/profile.gif';
   }
);
```

Comment: Its working on my end, please share your view and controller code snippet.